# Tomcat Server using 100% CPU?

Tags: profiling, tomcat6

I am new in using Tomcat Server. In one of the my web application i am using Tomcat 6.0.33 as a Server, it using 100% CPU. I couldn't find it why. Guys could you sort out this problem,

1. Why this tomcat using 100%CPU?
2. How to identify the problems of the above?
3. How to monitor the tomcat in windows?

Please, it would be more helpful for me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat itself doesn't use 100% CPU, it is not designed that way. Most probably it is some application that is deployed on it. To make 100% sure that it's not Tomcat just download its distribution and start it up - I bet you CPU usage will be closer to 0.

To tell which application inside your Tomcat is misbehaving you will need to use [profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) tools.

The best one IMO is Oracle's [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html). Start it from your JDK bin directory (it is called `jvisualvm.exe`), then follow the guide at the link. In particular its [Profiling section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html).

Comment: sure, the executable will not have `.exe` extension though :)

Comment: thanks, i will look into it. Also, u right, tomcat isn't the culprit. For me, i realized i need to increase heap size in tomcat's catalina.sh.